# LibGDX How to adjust mouse aim angle calculation when screen is resized

Tags: java, libgdx, angles, aiming

I'm starting with a screen resolution of `1280 x 960` and that is the default resolution where mouse aiming is calculated thus:

```
angleRad = (float) (Math.atan2(screenX - (screenWidth / 2), screenY - (screenHeight / 2)));
angle = (float) Math.toDegrees(angleRad - Math.PI / 2);
angle = Math.round(angle) <= 0 ? angle += 360 : angle;
if (Math.round(angle) == 360)
    angle = 0;
```

Which all works fine. But when the game is resized to some resolution with a vastly different ratio to the default, like for example `2560 x 1440` at full screen in my case, the aiming is off. The resize method is like this:

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    game.getViewport().update(width, height);
    control.screenWidth = width;
    control.screenHeight = height;
}
```

Where `control.screenWidth` and `control.screenHeight` are used in the above angle calculation and as the set resolution in other areas. The angle calculation when resized is roughly correct but tends to get further and further off course the further the aim is away from the player.

If the player aims straight up, down, left or right (N, S, W or E basically) then the aim is dead on, but veers off as aiming goes away from the player towards a screen edge - no doubt due to the resolution ratio difference.

We have these ratio differences which no doubt affect the angle calculation:

```
1280x960 1.33 ratio
2560x1440 1.77 ratio
```

But I'm not sure how to take into account these ratios to adjust the angle calculation accordingly in my code?

The crosshair and bullets are both off position. In the screenshot below the crosshair position in comparison with the mouse pointer can be seen. This is for resolution `2560x1440`. The code for the crosshair is this:

```
point = angleToVector((float) (angleRad + Math.PI)).scl(10000);
gs.getWorld().rayCast(callBack, pos, point);
```

`angleRad` is the mouse angle in radians, `pos` is the vector position of the player and `point` is the vector target position. This is the raycast callback

```
private RayCastCallback callBack = new RayCastCallback() {
    @Override
    public float reportRayFixture(Fixture fixture, Vector2 point, Vector2 normal, float fraction) {
            collision.set(point);
        return fraction;
};
```

[image]

Comment: Your angle calculation looks correct, though I'm confused why you would use angles here at all. A direction vector is simpler to calculate and use, with no trigonometry needed to encode/decode it. Can you show us the numbers you're getting for screenX and screenY for a particular problem case where the aim is off, what angle you get out, and what angle you expect instead? A screenshot of your game would help too - I'm assuming you're using a top-down view, but if you have an oblique or isometric view that could change things.

Comment: @DMGregory♦ A direction vector is better for mouse aiming? I thought it was normally done with angles. screenX and screenY give a number between 0 and the currently sized screen height or width with screenY 0 being the top of the screen. I forgot to mention I have an aim crosshair displaying on the screen too.

Comment: My general advice is to avoid angles like the plague absolutely any time that you can. ;) But I wasn't asking for the range of the variables, I was asking for a test case. Something of the form "Here is a screenshot where this code behaves incorrectly. On this frame, screenX is 42 and screenY is 49, the computed angle is X, but I think it should be Y instead"

Comment: When you crop your code down to tiny snippets like this, you hide information we need to be able to help you. Here, we can't see how `pos` is defined. I would strongly recommend (again) that you edit your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example. That is: every step that we would need to reproduce this problem in a new project. Once we can reproduce the problem, we can test potential fixes to be sure they'll work for you.

Comment: DMGregory♦ Strange I meant to write that pos was the player position etc but somehow left it. It's all there now.

Answer (score 0):

Here "point" is actually an offset vector (a relative shift in space, with a direction and distance).

```
point = angleToVector((float) (angleRad + Math.PI)).scl(10000);
```

Here "point" is being used as a position (an absolute location in space).

```
gs.getWorld().rayCast(callBack, pos, point);
```

So you're drawing your ray from the player position, `pos`, to a point 10000 units in your aiming direction *measured from the world origin*.

It looks to me like you want:

```
point = pos.cpy().add(angleToVector((float) (angleRad + Math.PI)).scl(10000));
```

to aim from the player position, not from the world origin.

Comment: This `point = pos.add(angleToVec((float) (angleRad + Math.PI)));` makes the program quit with error `Assertion failed: (r.LengthSquared() > 0.0f), function RayCast, file ./Box2D/Collision/b2DynamicTree.h, line 209.`. With or without the scaling by 10,000 it quits the same way. Might be you're onto something but I've no idea why it's throwing this error.

Comment: Right because as the documentation states, `Vector2.add` works by "returning a reference to itself" - ie. you haven't copied `pos` with that line, you've modified `pos`. So now `point` and `pos` point to the same vector and you're trying to cast a ray from a point to itself (zero length). You probably want to copy the vector first as shown in the edit above.

Comment: DMGregory♦ Ah ok interesting, I'll make a note of that since I think I've had that error before and Java error messages don't tell you a lot. But strangely doing it this way is exactly the same as the original way with the same issue....for some reason there's no difference in the mouse cursor and crosshair position. I added a shaperrenderer line in drawing from the player to the point to make it clearer too.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing updated test cases in your question, showing that line and the values you're getting in your key variables along the way.

Comment: Something else to troubleshoot: is your mapping of physics coordinates to screen pixel coordinates affected by aspect ratio? If you place a circle in your physics world, does it behave like an ellipse when you make your screen wider?

Comment: ♦ I guess if this was the problem then there would be a discrepancy with the default 1280x960 resolution as well, and not just in the high resolution. Must be something about the ratio? Really stumped on this one.

Comment: This was the only coding error I could spot in the code you've shared so far. I'd recommend stepping through your code with a fine-tooth comb, checking all of your assumptions and reading all the intermediate values along the way, until you find where it starts deviating from your expectation. If you need help with that, editing your question to include a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example will let other users do this too.

Comment: DMGregory♦ Yes a circle does turn into an ellipse at the higher resolution since the screen is made to fit the resolution. If it didn't it would have black bars, but I don't know how I would compensate for that still. I thought I already had a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example, not sure what else is needed.

Comment: Given that your last comment suggests the stretching of the view to fit the screen could be related to this problem, you should probably include the code that stretches the view to fit the screen, at minimum. What you've shared so far are tiny isolated snippets. Nothing I could put into a new, blank project and successfully compile it. That's a long way from Complete or Verifiable.

Comment: ♦ I think it must be some kind of bug with LibGDX since I'm using `FitViewport` which is supposed to maintain aspect ratio but it's clearly not if a circle is turning into an ellipse. `FillViewport` should be different but it has an identical result https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports I should have black bars but I don't.

Comment: ♦ Well yes that's always gonna be the problem with stackoverflow, short of posting my 100 file engine it's never gonna be completely clear. There's always this, that and the other that could be causing the problem as you dig into the neverending code that is a game engine.

Comment: DMGregory♦ The viewport code is just part of LibGDX anyway, can't really include that. I've got the viewport call in the resize method at the top of my question.

Comment: Hundreds if not thousands of games have used LibGDX viewports successfully. While engine bugs can occur, your first suspicion should always be "Maybe I'm using this wrong" and systematically check your assumptions. The symptoms you describe are consistent with a mismatch between the screen coordinates and your internal world/stage coordinates, so you should take time to edit your question and thoroughly document how you are setting up and updating that mapping.

Comment: ♦ No it was in fact a bug, for some reason the rayhandler prevents the screen from resizing properly...very odd indeed. Someone else had reported a similar issue where some other strange thing had stopped the viewport resizing as it should. Now someone has marked this question as off topic...off what topic? It's already a minimal, complete, verifiable example, but to catch this error it would have been any thing but 'minimal'. I would have had to paste half the engine in. The answer is right in the resize method anyway which is indeed part of my question.

Comment: Would you like to post your solution as an Answer?